# Java StringTemplate Iterating over List of Complex Object

Tags: java, list, stringtemplate

I have a class like so:

```
public class Foo {
    private String s;
}
```

And I have a list of said objects. I want to be able to iterate over this list and print out the string property `s`. I have the following code to render the string template:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
foos.add(new Foo("A"));
foos.add(new Foo("B"));
foos.add(new Foo("C"));
params.put("foos", foos);
ST st = new ST("Hello, $data.(\"foos\") : {foo | $foo.s;separator=\", \"$}$", '$', '$');
st.add("data", params);
template = st.render();
System.out.println(template);
```

But the output is just:

```
Hello, ABC
```

How do I properly iterate over that list and print it out with comma separation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your separator separates the elemnets of `foo.s`, not those of `foo`. Try

```
ST st = new ST("Hello, $data.(\"foos\") : {foo | $foo.s$};separator=\", \"$", '$', '$');
```